# How should one get Session object in a controller on Symfony 5.3?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5

I'm a little confused as to the "right" way to retrieve the current session object within a controller in Symfony 5.3. The [current documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html#managing-the-session) says to typehint an argument as `SessionInterface`. However, this [Symfony blog post](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-5-3-session-service-deprecation?utm_source=Symfony%20Blog%20Feed&utm_medium=feed) says `SessionInterface` has been deprecated in favor of using `RequestStack`.

In services it's clear that I should inject `RequestStack` and call `$requestStack->getSession()`. However, in most controller methods I'm already injecting the `Request` object which also has a `getSession()` method that seems to work.

**Is it okay to get the session from the `Request` object, or should I inject `RequestStack` in addition to `Request` in my controller methods *(this feels like duplication almost)***

---

A quick code example:

```php
// in a controller
public function myRoute(Request $request): Response
{
    $session = $request->getSession(); // this works
}

// seems silly to also inject RequestStack when I already have Request
public function myRoute(Request $request, RequestStack $requestStack): Response
{
    $reqestStack->getSession(); // this works
}

// the way current documentation shows
public function myRoute(Request $request, SessionInterface $session): Response
{
    // this causes a deprecation warning from injecting SessionInterface 
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The documentation has not yet been updated.<sup>*</sup>

In Symfony 5.3+, outside of controller context, you should get the session from the `RequestStack`, as you are doing and it's described on the blog. There it says the reasons why getting the session data from the `Request` object feels wrong, and why the `SessionInterface` is being deprecated in favour of the `RequestStack`:

> - Session is a data object (e.g. like the Request object) so there shouldn’t be a service defined for it in the container;
> - Sessions are not part of the HTTP specification (either HTTP/1.1, HTTP/2 or HTTP/3) because HTTP is stateless. That’s why it feels odd to handle sessions as part of the HttpFoundation component.

If you are *already* getting the `Request` object (e.g. you are on a controller context), you can get it from there directly as well, as `Request::getSession()` has not been deprecated. That's fine, and it's simply part of the convenience of working within the framework.

But if you are not, get the `RequestStack` instead of the `SessionInterface` directly.

```
public function myRoute(RequestStack $requestStack): Response
{
    $requestStack->getSession();
}
```

(And if you do this, you could get the `Request` object from there as well, swapping the injection of a data object with a service-like object to get that data).

<sup>*</sup> Remember that the docs themselves are open-source, and they welcome pull-requests to keep them updated!

Comment: I found the blog (specifically what you quoted) more confusing. It says it feels odd to handle sessions as part of the `HttpFoundation` component, yet the `RequestStack` is part of that component. Looking into the `RequestStack::getSession()` source code, all it's really doing is calling `Request::getSession()` anyway, so it feels like a wrapper/convenience method to me more than anything else. The docs definitely need some updating, I'll look into opening a PR for this. Thanks for the reply.